# implement in Clojure integer? in scheme

Tags: clojure, scheme

I'm new to Clojure, and can't find an equivalent of integer? in Chez scheme 8.4, mainly for test cases as below:

> (integer? 39.0)
>   => #t

The function I've come up so far is:

```
(defn actual-integer? [x] (or (= 0.0 (- x (int x))) (integer? x)))
```

Does it work when x is arbitrary number types or is there a better solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, strictly speaking `39.0` isn't an integer *literal* because it has the `.0` part at the end. A simple implementation of the procedure would be:

```
(defn actual-integer? [x] (== (int x) x))
```

Notice that the [`==` operator](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/==):

> Returns non-nil if nums all have the equivalent value (type-independent), otherwise false

Comment: I tested this version with Clojure 1.5.1, and below return false: (actual-integer? 3.0)